# Understanding why Foreign key references to Primary key in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

```
create table employee
 (emp_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment,
  fname varchar(20) not null,
  lname varchar(20) not null,
  start_date date not null,
  end_date date,
  superior_emp_id smallint unsigned,
  dept_id smallint unsigned,
  title varchar(20),
  assigned_branch_id smallint unsigned,
  constraint fk_e_emp_id 
    foreign key (superior_emp_id) references employee (emp_id),
  constraint fk_dept_id
    foreign key (dept_id) references department (dept_id),
  constraint fk_e_branch_id
    foreign key (assigned_branch_id) references branch (branch_id),
  constraint pk_employee primary key (emp_id)
 );
```

I'm studying this [Example](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596007270/LearningSQLExample.sql) and i noticed in `employee table`

```
emp_id is primary key
```

and `superior_emp_id which is a foreign key` references to the `emp_id` in the same table

creating foreign key which references to primary key in the same table why such a database design can any one help me ?

Comment: A superior is also an employee.  So the superior for emp_id=2 might be emp_id=1; basically a 1:1 relation to a row in the same table.

Comment: 1 to n actually. One superior can have many subordinates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thats how you would create a hierarchy, and <strike>would ensure that you can't have a child with no parent</strike> could also ensure you can't have a child with an invalid parent.

See also [Should you make a self-referencing table column a foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246477/should-you-make-a-self-referencing-table-column-a-foreign-key)

Comment: Sorry, should have said "could also ensure you can't have a child with an invalid parent" (regarding the idea of referential integrity itself as opposed to this specific case)

Comment: "Thats how you would create a hierarchy" -- I agree it *should* be a hierarchy but isn't it actually a tree?

Comment: @onedaywhen - Why do you consider a tree to not be a hierarchy?

Comment: In a hierarchy, if you fire my boss, I still have to answer to her boss.

Answer (score 6):

It's supposed to indicate that an empolyee can have a superior

```
emp_id, fname, lname, superior_emp_id
----------------------
1, 'Big', 'Boss', null,
2, 'Viswanathan', 'Iyer', 1
```

in this example Big Boss is your boss, and he himself has no bosses above him.

Comment: His parents really made a good guess about his future employment status when naming him! :)