# Foreign Key referencing Primary key in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have a table with two columns as the primary key. These two columns are also a foreign key that references the same table:
(This table was created some time ago by someone who has since left the company)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblItemLink](
    [ItemListID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblItemList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemListID] ASC,
    [ItemID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblItemLink]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblItemLink_tblItemLink] FOREIGN KEY([ItemListID], [ItemID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblItemLink] ([ItemListID], [ItemID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblItemLink] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblItemLink_tblItemLink]
GO
```

In practice, ItemID refers to tblItem.ItemID, and ItemListID is found nowhere else in the DB but there is a corresponding enum in the application.

Is there any reason for the primary key to also be a foreign key referencing itself (ie. some undocumented performance improvement), or is it just a mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of no reason why this, specifically, could provide a benefit - so I'm going to go with option 2 - a mistake.

Of course, if it was different columns in the same table, that would make sense, and as @Jignesh.Raj points out, that would form some kind of hierarchy.

You can even sometimes end up with multiple hierarchies within the same table with such multi-column references:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   GroupID int not null,
   ItemID int not null,
   ParentItemID int null,
   constraint PK_T PRIMARY KEY (GroupID,ItemID),
   constraint FK_T_Parent FOREIGN KEY (GroupID,ParentItemID) references T (GroupID,ItemID)
)
```

In the above, the `GroupID` column always references itself.

But as I say, with your current table, where *both* columns only reference themselves, it makes no sense.

Comment: Just to add to the reasons that this is most likely a mistake: when a new constraint is added using SSMS the default configuration is for the "primary key" and the "foreign key" to both refer to the primary key of the current table.

Answer (score 4):

Thats how you would create a hierarchy, and could also ensure you can't have a child with an invalid parent.

See also [Should you make a **self-referencing** table column a **foreign key**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246477/1793718)?

Comment: Yes, it would be a hierarchy if there was a foreign key referencing a primary key in the same table, but in this case, the primary key IS the foreign key - so each row really refers to itself.