# sql server column has foreign key to itself, and it is also a primary key, how is this possible

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am analysing the database tables and design, I have noticed that there is a table with a column interviewID which is a primary key to the table, it is also a foreign key, the relation says it is a foreign key to itself, how is this even possible. primary key says each value should be unique and not null but foreign key says it has to be one of the existing values? Something wrong with the design? or is there some logic behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new foreign key in SQL Server Management Studio all controls are set to crazy defaults: a self-referential foreign key on the first column of the table (usually the primary key column). I think somebody did this and just hit save.

It has no purpose whatsoever. Delete it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be wise to see the actual schema before deciding to delete? Self referential foreign keys are used in some basic ways see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246477/should-you-make-a-self-referencing-table-column-a-foreign-key

Comment: @yonitdm according to the OP the key references the same column of the same table. That never makes sense because the constraint is always satisfied. It says `T.ID` must be in the set of `T.ID`. That's useless.

Comment: did you mean delete the foreign key constraint on the column